# JOINS works very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

In my SQL-Server 2008 R2 i have a  SQL query:

```
SELECT
IceCrossing.WaterwayName as WaterWayName,
IceCrossing.Segment_ID as Segment_ID,
the_geom = Track.Track
FROM dbo.IceCrossing
LEFT JOIN Track ON IceCrossing.Segment_ID=Track.Segment_ID
```

There i want to select all rows from IceCrossing and if in Track exists row with same Segment_ID show it in result.  And there is problem with JOIN. Becouse its query works 4-5 seconds for return me my 260 rows. I was tried to change it:

```
SELECT
IceCrossing.WaterwayName as WaterWayName,
IceCrossing.Segment_ID as Segment_ID,
the_geom = Track.Track
FROM dbo.Track
RIGHT JOIN IceCrossing ON Track.Segment_ID=IceCrossing.Segment_ID
```

But same time.
Its possible to make it faster without make a any things with data base and table structures?

**UPDATE**

More info.
Track - 209 rows.
IceCrossing - 259 rows.
Segment_ID type - [uniqueidentifier]
How to know about indexes on this?

**UPDATE2**

How i understand my problem in the `the_geom` field. Becouse query:

```
    SELECT
IceCrossing.WaterwayName as WaterWayName,
IceCrossing.Segment_ID as Segment_ID,
FROM dbo.IceCrossing
LEFT JOIN Track ON IceCrossing.Segment_ID=Track.Segment_ID
```

Works within a second.
the_geom type - geometry its like a very long string.
What can i do in this case?

Comment: how many rows do you have in your tables? Do you have any indexes on Segment_ID column? what type you Segment_ID columns have?

Comment: @RomanPekar: I just updated question please look at it.

Comment: How are you running your query - inside SSMS? If not, how long does it take if you run it inside SSMS?

Comment: Well it' very strange that you query runs such a long time on that tiny data amount.

Comment: Yeah i work in SSMS. But i still dont know how to know about existing indexses in table? Without JOINS query works within 00.00.00 seconds

Comment: You can find out index details in SSMS - open Object Explorer, browse through Databases to find your database, browse through tables in your database to find Track and IceCrossing, then expand the Indexes node under each of those tables. (However, indexes should not be relevant if you only have 209 and 259 rows on each table.)

Comment: @MarkBannister: i was checked it anyway and how i see Segment_ID have not an any indexes in both tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The join is fine.  You may need an index, either on `Track(Segment_ID)` or `IceCrossing(Segment_ID)`.

With that volume of data, I'm surprised that the query could take so long.  Have you run the query multiple times and gotten consistent results?  Is anything else running on the server?

There is no difference in performance between the `left outer join` and `right outer join`.  They do the same thing.

Comment: I test it on notebook with Intel Core i3 and 4gb RAM.  I clicking just once to Execute query. When i test this query on real server query time was about 3-4 seconds.

Comment: How long does `select * from Track` take?  It could be the geometry object that is taking up all the time.

Comment: Yeah its a the_geom field take most time. Its possible to make something in this case?

Comment: @KliverMax . . . Do you need it?  Can you just extract some properties from it?

Comment: I use the_geom field for objects visualisation. I need it. But its so strange that SQL-Server work with this data type so slow. When i use PostgreSQL i can select whole table with ~50k objects in 1-2 seconds.

Comment: @KliverMax . . . I would suggest that you ask another question, specifically on retrieving geometry objects in your environment, on dba.stackexchange.  That site might have the expertise for solving or at least explaining the performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

have your tried simple `select * from Track`, `select * from IceCrossing`? If you have huge amount of data in one of your columns (for example, varbinary(max)), it could be not the query that is slow, but receiving all data at client side.

Try that query

```
select
    I.Segment_ID,
    T.Segment_ID
from dbo.IceCrossing as I
    left outer join Track as T on T.Segment_ID = I.Segment_ID
```

How long does it executing?

Comment: Your query work within 00.00.00 seconds. But when i add one more field in select T.the_geom query time was 21 seconds (but it return 54k rows). So how i understand my problem in the_geom fiels. I add info about it in question, please look at it.

Comment: So your problem is not join, but getting data on client. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I dont know. I have only one way: says to me boss that using SQL-Server for spatial data not a best way. But maybe you have a better idea?

Comment: well, I think that you should have some client to process your data? have you tried to call this query not from SSMS, but from you client? Have you considered taking only few necessary rows of data to client?